# Shell script for installation

Tags: shell, ubuntu

I need a shell script file for Installing Nginx With PHP5 (And PHP-FPM) And MySQL Support (LEMP) On Ubuntu 12.10. Can anyone direct me to create a shell script file to install these tools. Am new in creating shell script.

Your response should be appreciable!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shell script is, basically, a file with commands you'd execute anyway by hand in command line.

Start with creating it, with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

apt-get install ...

# do some other operations
```

Save it as script.sh. Now just change it's permissions, so it's executable:

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
```

Now it's ready to be invoked:

```
$ ./script.sh
```

Comment: Sir, I have one doubt. In the shell script we take git repo checkout. Then in the repo we have a configuration file to set database name, password etc. How to set replace these data using shell script?

Comment: Well, you can use Perl or sed for this task. On example to replace line in a conf file "password=" with "password=qwerty", you can use perl: perl -p -i -e 's/password=.*/password=qwerty/' conf.txt

Comment: Can u give me reference url to understand this?

Comment: You can, on example, read [this article](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/sandtr.html)

Comment: Hello Sir, how to change the configuration in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default using a shell script?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. I personally would use Perl with the general syntax: perl -p -i -e 's/TEXT_MATCH/REPLACEMENT/' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default. TEXT_MATCH is a regular expression matching the line you're trying to change. REPLACEMENT is a new text you want to put there. There is to little space here to go into much details. Try reading some articles online, on example: http://kb.iu.edu/data/afrk.html.

Comment: Thank u so much Sir for ur quick response :)

Comment: Sir, My doubt is it possible to change this file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default from shell script. I tried with replace string but I have got permission denied.. Can u give me the best way to change this file?

Comment: Can u create a chat room to chat with me..

Comment: Sir.. I need ur help.. Can U come to our chat room?

Comment: Hello Kamil Can u come to chat room?